# jest telling me to put Link inside Router

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Im new at react-testing-library!

I'm getting this error when I test the Navbar component

"Invariant failed: You should not use  `<Link>` outside a `<Router>`"

my Navbar component :

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Logo>
        <h3>
          <LogoLink to="">conduit</LogoLink>
        </h3>
      </Logo>
      <NavList>
        <Li>
          <NavLink to="">Home</NavLink>
        </Li>
        <Li>
          <NavLink to="signin">Sign in</NavLink>
        </Li>
        <Li>
          <NavLink to="signup">Sign up</NavLink>
        </Li>
      </NavList>
    </Nav>
  );
}

export default Navbar;
```

- my test:

  ```
   import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    import React from 'react';
    import Navbar from './Navbar';

    it('should render the Navbar component', () => {
      const mockNavbar = jest.fn();
      const { debug } = render(<Navbar navbar={mockNavbar} />);
      debug();
    });
  ```

I'm also using styled- component, my styled component:

```
const LogoLink = styled(Link)`
  color: #5cb85c;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
`;

const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aba6a6;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2e2c2c;
  }
`;
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/testing): *"If you try to unit test one of your components that renders a `<Link>` or a `<Route>`... , we recommend you wrap your unit test in one of the Router components: the base `Router` with a history prop, or a `<StaticRouter>`, `<MemoryRouter>`, or `<BrowserRouter>` (if window.history is available as a global in the test enviroment)."*

Comment: ohhh ty worked! @JanezKuhar

Answer (score 1):

Your `<App>` probably not wrapped by Router so you should wrap your app between `<Router>`. In this case I'm referencing App as your first component when you create create-react-app because I do not know your code structure.

Comment: Can you check the next comment

Comment: also the project is working fine but the error only in the test !
could it be as rules of the company building style ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Content} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: <Header /> component has the Navbar